# making running mean of numbers in a row

Tags: r, dataframe, average, mean

I have the following table

```
>anna2
     name   from      to       result
     11     66607     66841       5
     11     66846     67048       6 
     11     67409     68216       7
     11     69025     69289       12
     11     70172     70560       45
```

what I want is to create column which will have averages of the result in a row....

what I mean is that I want to have an average of the values 5,6,7 then the 6,7,12 then the 7,12,45 then the 12,45.....

BUT the mean of the 5,6,7 i want to be allocated to the 66846-67048 the mean of the 6,7,12 i want to be allocated in to the 67409 68216

so every time i want to have the mean to the center of the 3 values that i have used to calculate that because then i need to make a plot where my x is going to be the from-start and the y the mean value

how can i do that?

thank you in advance

Best regards
Anna

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean running mean with a window size of 3?

```
library(zoo)
annna2$rollmean <- rollmean(anna2$result, 3, fill = NA)
```